# AWS Lambda + SQS opentelemetry python Link field value, can I configure it to be the traceparent?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, open-telemetry

According to all the links PRs, looks like we are using "_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID as a Span Link". However, the information I am trying to get from "Links" field is actually in the "traceparent" not the "_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID". Is there a way to config that ? Or it is not what the spec says and I need to add some customized code ?

**What I did**:
I manually compiled and created a layer with this PR's changes. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/pull/1657.
I have a python process running locally to put a message into a sqs. Then a Lambda function read the message and print.

**What I expect**:
I can get my producer's traceID in the SpanLink field. So my backend can connect those 2 traces.

Code of producer:

```
import boto3

# Create SQS client
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/account_number/shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2'


# Send message to SQS queue
response = sqs.send_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    DelaySeconds=10,
    MessageAttributes={
        'Title': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': 'The Whistler'
        },
        'Author': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': 'John Grisham'
        },
        'WeeksOn': {
            'DataType': 'Number',
            'StringValue': '6'
        }
    },
    MessageBody=(
        'Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for '
        'week of 12/11/2016.'
    )
)
```

Code of consumer lambda:

```
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        payload = record["body"]
        print('------------ Trace parent------------',  record['messageAttributes']['traceparent'])
        xray_env = os.getenv('_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID')
        print('------------ X_RAY ------------', xray_env)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(str(payload))
    }
```

Trace of my producer:

```
2023-04-27T15:40:01.366-0700    info    TracesExporter  {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging", "#spans": 2}
2023-04-27T15:40:01.367-0700    info    ResourceSpans #0
Resource SchemaURL: 
Resource attributes:
     -> telemetry.sdk.language: Str(python)
     -> telemetry.sdk.name: Str(opentelemetry)
     -> telemetry.sdk.version: Str(1.17.0)
     -> telemetry.auto.version: Str(0.38b0)
     -> service.name: Str(unknown_service)
ScopeSpans #0
ScopeSpans SchemaURL: 
InstrumentationScope opentelemetry.instrumentation.botocore 0.38b0
Span #0
    Trace ID       : 755953bd01c1f767dc857d1f45c511a2
    Parent ID      : 36f550ea0824e169
    ID             : 3899d8d6808d891e
    Name           : SQS.SendMessage
    Kind           : Client
    Start time     : 2023-04-27 22:40:00.890738 +0000 UTC
    End time       : 2023-04-27 22:40:01.175802 +0000 UTC
    Status code    : Unset
    Status message : 
Attributes:
     -> rpc.system: Str(aws-api)
     -> rpc.service: Str(SQS)
     -> rpc.method: Str(SendMessage)
     -> aws.region: Str(us-west-2)
     -> aws.queue_url: Str(https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/account_number/shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2)
     -> messaging.system: Str(aws.sqs)
     -> messaging.url: Str(https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/account_number/shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2)
     -> messaging.destination: Str(shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2)
     -> aws.request_id: Str(5ba87e13-355c-5d2a-a02d-22d7c95da701)
     -> retry_attempts: Int(0)
     -> http.status_code: Int(200)
     -> messaging.message_id: Str(83a3af87-ad0d-4c0d-82bb-7d0b2f25acc7)
ScopeSpans #1
ScopeSpans SchemaURL: 
InstrumentationScope opentelemetry.instrumentation.boto3sqs 0.38b0
Span #0
    Trace ID       : 755953bd01c1f767dc857d1f45c511a2
    Parent ID      : 
    ID             : 36f550ea0824e169
    Name           : shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2 send
    Kind           : Producer
    Start time     : 2023-04-27 22:40:00.890165 +0000 UTC
    End time       : 2023-04-27 22:40:01.175911 +0000 UTC
    Status code    : Unset
    Status message : 
Attributes:
     -> messaging.system: Str(aws.sqs)
     -> messaging.destination: Str(shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2)
     -> messaging.destination_kind: Str(queue)
     -> messaging.url: Str(https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/account_number/shuwpan-sqs-between-f1-f2)
     -> messaging.message_id: Str(83a3af87-ad0d-4c0d-82bb-7d0b2f25acc7)
    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging"}
```

Trace of my consumer:

```
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: 2023-04-27T22:40:22.003Z        info        TracesExporter        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging", "#spans": 1}
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: 2023-04-27T22:40:22.005Z        info        ResourceSpans #0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: Resource SchemaURL:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: Resource attributes:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> telemetry.sdk.language: Str(python)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> telemetry.sdk.name: Str(opentelemetry)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> telemetry.sdk.version: Str(1.17.0)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> cloud.region: Str(us-west-2)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> cloud.provider: Str(aws)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> faas.name: Str(shuwpan-consumer-for-python-link-testing)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> faas.version: Str($LATEST)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> faas.instance: Str(2023/04/27/[$LATEST]1236d5f86959443b9bd05d8594ab8d87)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> service.name: Str(shuwpan-consumer-for-python-link-testing)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> telemetry.auto.version: Str(0.38b0)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: ScopeSpans #0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: ScopeSpans SchemaURL:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: InstrumentationScope opentelemetry.instrumentation.aws_lambda 0.38b0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: Span #0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Trace ID       : 2b858d51cd48a453967cbf901408537e
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Parent ID      :
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     ID             : 69e6a1a910a45dfa
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Name           : lambda_function.lambda_handler
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Kind           : Consumer
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Start time     : 2023-04-27 22:40:13.475879717 +0000 UTC
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     End time       : 2023-04-27 22:40:13.53614176 +0000 UTC
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Status code    : Unset
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:     Status message :
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: Attributes:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> faas.id: Str(arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:account_number:function:shuwpan-consumer-for-python-link-testing)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> faas.execution: Str(dc3423a5-f503-55b9-b472-7f610efc6f73)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: Links:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]: SpanLink #0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> Trace ID: 644af9cb30e86117070956834d350c2a
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> ID: 120cf943762a7b10
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> TraceState:
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> DroppedAttributesCount: 0
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:      -> Attributes::
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:           -> source: Str(x-ray-env)
Apr 27 22:40:22 ip-10-0-0-9 appdotelcol[12416]:         {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "traces", "name": "logging"}
```

Log from lambda:

```
------------ Trace parent------------ {'stringValue': '00-755953bd01c1f767dc857d1f45c511a2-36f550ea0824e169-01', 'stringListValues': [], 'binaryListValues': [], 'dataType': 'String'}
------------ X_RAY ------------ Root=1-644af9cb-30e86117070956834d350c2a;Parent=120cf943762a7b10;Sampled=1;Lineage=772d7282:0
```

Comment: Did you find some solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No, I think the feature is not available on python side by the look of the code. (but Java worked).

Comment: Good to know that with Java is currently working. Thanks @shuwpan